# How to watch gradients in Keras for MNIST

Tags: tensorflow, keras, watch, gradient-descent, mnist

I want to plot the gradients for each epoch and trying to obtain the values using gradient tape. But I am getting the following error.

```
batch_size = 128
epochs = 15
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="adam", metrics=["accuracy"])
history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs, validation_split=0.1)
loss_val = history.history['loss']
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    # Forward pass.
    tape.watch(model.trainable_weights)
    grads = tape.gradient(loss_val, model.trainable_weights)
"""
## Evaluate the trained model
"""
score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0)
print("Test loss:", score[0])
print("Test accuracy:", score[1])
```

I am getting the following error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-f04339bdcbcf> in <module>
     12     # Forward pass.
     13     tape.watch(model.trainable_weights)
---> 14     grads = tape.gradient(loss_val, model.trainable_weights)
     15 """
     16 ## Evaluate the trained model

~/.conda/envs/tf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/backprop.py in gradient(self, target, sources, output_gradients, unconnected_gradients)
    983     flat_targets = []
    984     for t in nest.flatten(target):
--> 985       if not t.dtype.is_floating:
    986         logging.vlog(
    987             logging.WARN, "The dtype of the target tensor must be "

AttributeError: 'numpy.dtype' object has no attribute 'is_floating'
```

Comment: Is tf.GradientTape expecting you to pass it a tensor? Based on this message, I would think so -"The dtype of the target tensor must be ". Convert your numpy array to a tensor and see how you go.

Comment: Error is fixed. by changing the line as below:                                                               grads = tape.gradient(model.total_loss, model.trainable_weights) But when i print grads, I am getting [None, None, None, None, None, None]